# Get all object attributes in Python?

Tags: python, introspection, python-2.6

Is there a way to get **all** attributes/methods/fields/etc. of an object in Python?

`vars()` is *close* to what I want, but it doesn't work unless an object has a `__dict__`, which isn't always true (e.g. it's not true for a `list`, a `dict`, etc.).

Comment: For getting the attributes of a `attrs` object, there's [`__attrs_attrs__`](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/extending.html).

Answer (score 810, accepted):

Use the built-in function [`dir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir).

Comment: note that the behavior of `dir()` is often manipulated to show *interesting* attributes, rather than strictly all;  for instance it doesn't show attributes inherited through a metaclass, or it may be overridden with a `__dir__` method.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: It's fine for what I need... thinking about it too much would give me a headache. ;)

Comment: It also doesn't show introspection properties such as `func_defaults`.

Comment: @mouad why do I get this though >> dir(pyrenderdoc)
IronPython.Runtime.List ?

Answer (score 190):

I use `__dict__` and `dir(<instance>)`

**Example**:

```
class MyObj(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = 'Chuck Norris'
    self.phone = '+6661'

obj = MyObj()
print(obj.__dict__)
print(dir(obj))

# Output:  
# obj.__dict__ --> {'phone': '+6661', 'name': 'Chuck Norris'}
#
# dir(obj)     --> ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__',
#               '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', 
#               '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', 
#               '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', 
#               '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 
#               '__weakref__', 'name', 'phone']
```

Comment: The OP *specifically* mentions that he is interested in cases where there is no `__dict__` - otherwise he could use `vars`

Comment: vars() is close to what I want, but it doesn't work unless an object has a __dict__, which isn't always true (e.g. it's not true for a list, a dict, etc.). he clearly said that  is NOT what he wants

Answer (score 123):

What you probably want is [`dir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir).

The catch is that classes are able to override the special `__dir__` method, which causes `dir()` to return whatever the class wants (though they are encouraged to return an accurate list, this is not enforced). Furthermore, some objects may implement dynamic attributes by overriding `__getattr__`, may be RPC proxy objects, or may be instances of C-extension classes. If your object is one these examples, they may not have a `__dict__` *or* be able to provide a comprehensive list of attributes via `__dir__`: many of these objects may have so many dynamic attrs it doesn't won't actually know *what* it has until you try to access it.

In the short run, if `dir()` isn't sufficient, you could write a function which traverses `__dict__` for an object, then `__dict__` for all the classes in `obj.__class__.__mro__`; though this will only work for normal python objects. In the long run, you may have to use duck typing + assumptions - if it looks like a duck, cross your fingers, and hope it has `.feathers`.

Comment: what if I want to store the results returned by dir()?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but... `attrs = dir(obj)` will store the array of attributes as strings in `attrs`. Then to access them, you can always use `getattr(obj, attrs[i])` to get the `i`th attribute in the `attrs` array.

Comment: `__dict__ ` this function really help me a lot.

Answer (score 95):

You can use `dir(your_object)` to get the attributes and `getattr(your_object, your_object_attr)` to get the values

usage :

```
for att in dir(your_object):
    print (att, getattr(your_object,att))
```

Comment: Thanks, It's what I'm looking for a long dam time

Comment: `for attr in dir(obj): print(attr +'()') if callable(getattr(obj, attr)) else print(attr)` # Will print parentheses immediately after any callables (functions, methods, classes, etc.)

Comment: Btw,  this formatting `print(f'{att} : {getattr(myobject,att)}\n')` may help you to read better your ouput

Comment: attribs = lambda obj: [o for o in dir(obj) if not o.startswith('_')] works fine for me.