# Python - getting post id on Facebook GraphAPI with Facepy

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to get the id of my post something like

> graph = GraphAPI(access_token)
>
> graph.post(all data)
>
> print graph.response

unfortunately response is not an attribute for GraphAPI

> AttributeError: 'GraphAPI' object has no attribute 'response'

anyone know how to get the post id or the comment id etc (like using Graph API Explorer , after every request you get the post id)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6886507/2327328 to get available attributes of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
response = graph.post(data)

print response['id']
```

Comment: thanks, this really helps... now to turn post id into a link