# python For loop for class attributes?

Tags: python, class

Is there a way i can loop a function with an argument in a class if that argument is not equal to None? I know how to do this with a lot of if loops, but is there another way I can do this?

Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
class Name:
    def __init__(self,name,favfood,favcolour,favsport):
        self.name = name
        self.favfood = favfood
        self.favcolour = favcolour
        self.favsport = favsport

henry = Name("Henry","Sushi","Blue",None)
```

I want a function that prints out all his favourite things, but will skip it if it is None, a for loop for classes pretty much.

Is there a way to have a forloop for every attribute in a class?

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886493/get-all-object-attributes-in-python`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) attribute of the `self` object:

```
class Name:
    def __init__(self,name,favfood,favcolour,favsport):
        self.name = name
        self.favfood = favfood
        self.favcolour = favcolour
        self.favsport = favsport
        for key, value in self.__dict__.items():
            if value is not None:
                print('%s: %s' % (key, value))

henry = Name("Henry","Sushi","Blue",None)
```

This outputs:

```
name: Henry
favfood: Sushi
favcolour: Blue
```

Comment: is there a way to use the key variable as an attribute? For example, i can call the attribute with henry.key

Comment: The only problem is that not all objects have a `__dict__` attribute... When a class defines a `__slots__` attribute, its objects have no `__dict__`.

Answer (score 0):

*Updated Would use the `__dict__` attribute as @blhsing suggested

```
class Name:
    def __init__(self,name,favfood,favcolour,favsport):
        self.name = name
        self.favfood = favfood
        self.favcolour = favcolour
        self.favsport = favsport

    def print_favs(self):
        '''even better using @blh method'''
        [print(f'{k}: {v}') for k, v in self.__dict__.items() if v != None]



henry = Name("Henry","Sushi","Blue",None)
henry.print_favs()
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 helping.py 
> name: Henry
> favfood: Sushi
> favcolour: Blue
> ```

Comment: Don't. `self.lista` contains the original values of the attributes. If an attribute receives a new value, `self.lista` will remain unchanged.