# Syntax error when calling "from" attribute of a JSON object

Tags: python, json, api, ringcentral, json-api-response-converter

I am using RingCentral API to get call log information.

I am interested in an attribute called `from` which tells us who was the caller who made the call. To access the caller name, I need to access a call record -> then go to the last leg (root of the call) and then get the from attribute, and then get the name of the caller.

E.g:

> "from": {
> "name": "andy murray",
> "phoneNumber": "+44712345656"
> }

```
resp = platform.get('/restapi/v1.0/account/~/call-log', params)       
for record in resp.json().records:
    print(record.legs[-1].from.name)
```

After running this command, I am getting error:

```
      File "demo.py", line 43
        print(record.legs[-1].from.name )
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It looks like Python is not able to comprehend that this "from" is not part of Python itself. How can I define Python to consider this as an attribute of a JSON object?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: A JSON object loads as a Python dict.  You need to use slicing - `record.legs[-1]['from']['name']` for example - rather than attribute access.  Since the keys are now just strings, it's no longer a problem that `from` is a Python keyword.

Comment: @jasonharper I am not converting it into python dict. It is working for all other attributes like :

record.legs[-1].recording.uri.     It just fails when I try to access "from" attribute

Comment: Then it would appear that you aren't using Python's standard `json` module.  I'd still suggest trying slicing, at least for this one attribute name.  The alternative would be to use `getattr(x, 'from')`.

Comment: Thanks mate. I found a workaround, I tried getattr, but still got the same error. Then, I called record.legs[-1].__dict__ 
and found out all attributes of json object. I found that, there was no attribute named "from", it was "from_".  However, with postman I was getting "from" attribute, I guess its the way python handles json objects (by renaming "from" to "from_" to avoid conflicts?)

Comment: What library are you using? This isn't Python's standard JSON parser.

Comment: I am using sdk of RingCentral, making API calls to fetch data. Data is returned in an "ApiResponse" format. I convert that into .json. Using object.json() method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `__dict__` to get all attributes of object.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39392891/9024042

As mentioned in the answer of the attached post. I called `record.legs[-1].__dict__` and found out all attributes of json object.

I found that, there was no attribute named "from",
It was "from_".

I hope it helps someone with the same issue