# Create child class object using parent class instance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

lets say we have class A and it has one instance - x. How to make a child class of class A where I would be able to pass x as an argument and get all its parameters and pass it to child class object. precisely speaking I want to do something like this.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, parameter1, parameter2):
        self.parameter1 = parameter1
        self.parameter2 = parameter2




class B(A):
    def __init__(self, Ainstance, someParameter):
        super().__init__(**Ainstance.__dict__)
        self.someParameter = someParameter

x = A(parameter1='1', parameter2='2')

x = B(x, someParameter='3')

print(x.parameter1)
print(x.parameter2)
print(x.someParameter)
```

the goal is to create a class where I would be able to get all the parameters of parent class object, and add my own attributes. The problem in the code above is I won't be able to do that with all classes because not all of them has `__dict__` attribute.

Comment: 1. You don't have to do it with all classes, only with class A, as you pass an A-instance?
2. Why are you doing this? Ask a question on how to solve THAT problem. This way is probably not it.

Comment: While you can technically do it, I don't see why we want to do this, though? What's the reasoning behind this?

Comment: The problem is there is no class A, there is a library class. I just wanted to create the exact same object but with some additional attributes. But I can't add attributes to the library class. OOP is still complicating thing for me so I wanted to solve my problem this way, But by the looks of it, this was not appropriate way.

Comment: A library class? Did you mean that you just want to derive from it?

Comment: Not quite. I want to use instance of a library class as an argument to pass its parameters to a child class object. so I will have the exact same object, with additional attributes and methods. To be more precise I use socket class of socket library. and when new client connects I am given a client object and using this client object I want to create a new object but with username, address associated with socket and other attributes/methods.

Comment: Could you just add those attributes to the socket?

Comment: No I couldn't. I get this error while doing so:
AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'username'

Comment: Yes I did exactly that, I even tried setattr(server_socket, 'username', 'some username') and both gave the same error. I don't know what's wrong. I guess another subject to search up.

Comment: See my answer about using a `proxy` pattern in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this example code which I use to remind myself how to construct a `proxy`.

```py
#soProxyPattern

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tag_name = 'name'
    def foo(self):
        return 'foo'
    def bar(self, param):
        return param
    
class Container:
    def __init__(self, contained):
        self.contained = contained
        self.user_name = 'username'

    def zoo(self):
        return 0
    
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if hasattr(self.contained, item):
            return getattr(self.contained,item)
        #raise item

c = Container(Example())
print(c.zoo())
print(c.foo())
print(c.bar('BAR'))
print(c.tag_name)
print(c.user_name)
```

The output is:

```
0
foo
BAR
name
username
```

This shows that `Container` can have its own attributes (methods or variables) which you can access over and above *all* of the attributes of the contained instance.

Comment: Worked just as I wanted. That's a great concept. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. You can upvote this answer if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **dict** you could use the dir and getattr like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, parameter1, parameter2):
        self.parameter1 = parameter1
        self.parameter2 = parameter2


 class B(A):
     def __init__(self, Ainstance, someParameter):
        parameters = {param: getattr(Ainstance, param) for param in dir(Ainstance) if not param.startswith("__")} 
        super().__init__(**parameters)
        self.someParameter = someParameter
```

For a more detailed explanation see: [Get all object attributes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886493/get-all-object-attributes-in-python)

Comment: Did you intend to edit the other answer?

Comment: Oh yes, thank you for pointing it out

Comment: Thanks for answer. It does exactly what I asked for but it still does not solve my problem because what I'm trying to do is create copy of an instance but apparently copying only attributes is not enough.