# Pythonic way to know in which parent an attribute was defined

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

If I have this tree of classes:

```py
@dataclass
class Parent():
  p: int = 42

@dataclass
class Child(Parent):
  c: int = 0

obj = Child()
```

From the object `obj`, is there an easy way to know that `p` was defined in `Parent`, and `c` in `Child`?

I am looping via `__mro__` from the top, getting the list of attributes there, and going lower in the hierarchy I get the new attributes not yet defined. It works, but I wonder if there is a more pythonic way.

**Edit: Context**

It is about autogenerated classes, describing real world electricity networks.

Image having these 3 classes, defining a tree:

- `Equipment` class defining `name`
- `ConductingEquipment` defining `resistance`
- `Cable` defining `material`.

There will of course be more equipment types and more conducting equipment types.
There is one standard exchange format for this, which requires giving the fully qualified attribute name, so `Equipment.name` even for a `Cable`.

So in this admittedly weird context, this is something I do need to do.

Comment: What's the context - what do you do with that information?

Comment: Will it be useful...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-built-in-function-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of-a
(or)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886493/get-all-object-attributes-in-python

Comment: I don't think there's a "pythonic" way because this isn't something you should need to do.

Comment: @Barmar Sadly I do need to do it (context added) but I am afraid that you are right, and there is no easier way than looping manually.

Answer (score 1):

> Accessing The Annotations Dict Of An Object In Python 3.10 And Newer
>
> Python 3.10 adds a new function to the standard library: inspect.get_annotations(). In Python versions 3.10 and newer, calling
> this function is the best practice for accessing the annotations dict
> of any object that supports annotations. This function can also
> “un-stringize” stringized annotations for you.
>
> ```
> If for some reason inspect.get_annotations() isn’t viable for your use case, you may access the __annotations__ data member manually.
> ```
>
> Best practice for this changed in Python 3.10 as well: as of Python
> 3.10, o.**annotations** is guaranteed to always work on Python functions, classes, and modules. If you’re certain the object you’re
> examining is one of these three specific objects, you may simply use
> o.**annotations** to get at the object’s annotations dict.
>
> However, other types of callables–for example, callables created by functools.partial()–may not have an **annotations** attribute
> defined. When accessing the **annotations** of a possibly unknown
> object, best practice in Python versions 3.10 and newer is to call
> getattr() with three arguments, for example getattr(o,
> '**annotations**', None).
>
> Before Python 3.10, accessing **annotations** on a class that defines no annotations but that has a parent class with annotations
> would return the parent’s **annotations**. In Python 3.10 and newer,
> the child class’s annotations will be an empty dict instead.

> In Python 3.9 and older, accessing the annotations dict of an object is much more complicated than in newer versions. The problem is a
> design flaw in these older versions of Python, specifically to do with
> class annotations.
>
> Best practice for accessing the annotations dict of other
> objects–functions, other callables, and modules–is the same as best
> practice for 3.10, assuming you aren’t calling
> inspect.get_annotations(): you should use three-argument getattr() to
> access the object’s **annotations** attribute.
>
> Unfortunately, this isn’t best practice for classes. The problem is
> that, since **annotations** is optional on classes, and because
> classes can inherit attributes from their base classes, accessing the
> **annotations** attribute of a class may inadvertently return the annotations dict of a base class.

**Python**

```
@dataclass
class Parent():
    p: int = 42

@dataclass
class Child(Parent):
    c: int = 0

class Foo(Child):
    pass

parent = Parent()
child = Child()
foo = Foo()
```

**output 3.7**

```
print(f"Parent object annotations: {parent.__annotations__}")
print(f"Child object annotations: {child.__annotations__}")
print(f"Foo object annotations: {foo.__annotations__}")

Parent object annotations: {'p': <class 'int'>}
Child object annotations: {'c': <class 'int'>}
Foo object annotations: {'c': <class 'int'>} # <-- Wrong :(
```

**python 3.10**

```
print(f"Parent object annotations: {inspect.get_annotations(type(parent))}")
print(f"Child object annotations: {inspect.get_annotations(type(child))}")
print(f"Foo object annotations: {inspect.get_annotations(type(foo))}")

Parent object annotations: {'p': <class 'int'>}
Child object annotations: {'c': <class 'int'>}
Foo object annotations: {}
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/annotations.html

Comment: Thanks, but the tree needs to be known (or found out by looping through `__mro__`), which was my initial solution.

Comment: I found the question interesting! There must be a way :P. I will take another look and come back to you.

Comment: Oh, there is a way (simili-one-liner): `all_attrs={}; for parent in reversed(self.__class__.__mro__[:-1]): for f in fields(parent):  if  f.name not in all_attrs:  do_something()` but more pythonic? If you find something, I would be very curious to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```py
for attribute in vars(obj).keys():
    if attribute in vars(obj.__class__):
        print(f"Attribute '{attribute}' defined in {obj.__class__.__name__}")
    else:
        print(
            f"Attribute '{attribute}' inherited from {obj.__class__.__base__.__name__}"
        )
```

**Output**

```bash
Attribute 'p' inherited from Parent
Attribute 'c' defined in Child
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not fit my use case, which actually has multiple levels of inheritance. Then looping (probably with `__mro__ `) looks like the way to go.